# Stuck on the login page

Tags: ubuntu

It is strange this morning. I tried to enter on my account, but when I enter my password, the screen was black and came back on the login page (login loop). I have easily access to the terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. I am using the version 16.10 on Ubuntu, and I can't find the file `.Xauthority`. Could anyone have a solution for that kind of problem? However, I could access my account with `sudo startx`, but chrome decides to not working.

I tried before rebooting

1. `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp`
2. to look for `.Xauthority` and `lightDM`, but both doesn't exist.
3. `sudo apt purge nvidia-*`
4. `sudo apt dist-upgrade`
5. change `gdm3` for `lightDM`

**P.S** I have a X1 Carbon 5th generation. Furthermore, I know there exists many similar pages, but none of them helped me so far.

This is probably an important details, but I don't know what is that. When I did `sudo apt update`:

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/blueman/ppa/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: `sudo startx` is wrong; you should be able just to run `startx`. Have you got some root-owned files in your (non-root) home directory? If so, fix the ownership and try again. See http://askubuntu.com/a/223634

Answer (score 5):

> I could access my account with `sudo startx`

Then the problem is likely that some file or directory in your home directory belongs to root. Your normal session startup fails because it can't access that file.

Run `find ~ ! -user $(id -u)` to locate files under your home directory that don't belong to you.

Answer (score 4):

When the screen goes black and then immediately rotates back to the login screen, that usually means something went wrong while your session was being started. To debug what exactly, the best way forward is to check the error log that your X session creates:

```
cat ~/.xsession-errors
```

Hopefully the programs that are started at startup print something to stderr explaining how and why they fail to start up properly. If they don't, then you'll have to be more creative. A few options you could try:

- If your login screen allows you to change the session, then try to change it to something else (e.g., try logging in with gnome rather than kde, or vice versa). If that works, you'll know something is wrong with your usual user interface, and that it's not something that's *always* started, like ssh-agent or some such.
- Try moving away the configuration files that start your session. Usually these files are in `~/.config`, so something like `mv .config .config-backup` followed by a new login might work. If that works, try to remember which configuration options you changed during your last session, and find out how they are written to your `~/.config`; then you may be able to remove that setting from your `.config-backup` directory, and move it back to its rightful place (by doing `rm -rf .config; mv .config-backup .config` while you're not logged in).